# Elasticssearch Nest Synonyms 2.XX

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, synonym

I'm a newbie for elasticsearch and we are evaluate elasticsearch for our webstore. One important feature is the usage of synonyms. Unfortunately I'm not able to create a index with synonyms. Please can anybody help me how I can use the synonyms feature. I didn't find any sample for this feature and elasticsearch 2.xx. The goal should be if I search for Hills the entry of Royal will be find.

I use the following code:

```
private ElasticClient GetClient()
        {
            var node = new Uri(ES_URI);

            var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri).DefaultIndex("product");
            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            return client;

        }


public void CreateSynonymIndex()
        {
            Product product = new Product()
            {
                Id = "2",
                ProductName = "Royal",
                Description = "Katzenfutter für Nierkranke"


            };


            var client = GetClient();
            client.DeleteIndex("product");
            var syn = new[] { "royal, hills => royal" };

            ICreateIndexResponse respose = client.CreateIndex("product", c => c

            .Mappings(mp => mp.Map<Product>(d => d.
              Properties(p => p.String(n => n.Name(name => name.ProductName).Index(FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)))))

               .Settings(s => s
               .Analysis(an => an
                .Tokenizers(at=>at.Pattern("synonymTokenizer",pa=>pa.Pattern("Test")))
               .Analyzers(a=>a.Custom("synonymAnalyser",ca =>ca
                .Tokenizer("synonymTokenizer")
                .Filters(new List<string> { "synonym" })))
               .TokenFilters(tf => tf
                .Synonym("synonym", sy => sy.Synonyms(syn)
               .Tokenizer("whitespace")
                .IgnoreCase(true)))))
                );

            client.Index(product);


        }

public void ES_Search()
        {
            var client = GetClient();
            var response = client.Search<Product>(search => search
    .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b
        .Should(
           // s => s.Match(m => m.Query("sometest").Field(f => f.ProductName).Boost(1.1)),
            s => s.Match(m => m.Query("hills").Field(f => f.ProductName).Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(1)))
        ))));

            var response1 = client.Search<Product>(s => s.Query(q => q.Term(p => p.ProductName, "hills")));
```

}

Regards,

Dominik

Comment: Are you using NEST 2.x?

Comment: Hi, I'm using NEST V 2.4.6. I need a working sample for searching with synonyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created analyzer with synonyms, but you are not using it. You need to tell elasticsearch that `ProductName` field should use `synonymAnalyser` analyzer.

```
.Mappings(mp => mp.Map<Product>(d => d.
    Properties(p => p.String(n => n
        .Name(name => name.ProductName)
        .Analyzer("synonymAnalyser")
        .Index(FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)))))
```

I noticed few more things though:

- remeber that document is not immediately available in elasticsearch after calling `client.Index(..)` method. It will take some miliseconds. Searching just right after indexing document, you may not find it. You can read more about it [here](http://igor.kupczynski.info/2014/10/20/elasticsearch-refresh.html)
- I don't know if you creat `ElasticClient` with default index, because you didn't share it. If not, you will have to specify it in your search calls e.g. 
  `client.Search<Product>(s => s.Index("product"))`.

Hope that helps you.